# ¿Cuál es el origen de 'guácala'?

Tags: etimología, interjecciones

Según tengo entendido, la palabra [*guácala*](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=gu%C3%A1cala) se usa para expresar asco:

> ¡Guácala! Hallaron partículas de excremento en agua mineral.

¿De dónde viene esa palabra? ¿Cuál es su origen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parece ser que viene de la palabra ["guacal"](https://www.google.com/search?q=guacal).

> Con frecuencia el contenido de los guacales después de su uso es agua sucia. Esta agua sucia solían algunas personas lanzarlas por las puertas hacia la calle… el pasante ocasional y sin mucha suerte podía recibir esa ‘guacalada’.

La propia palabra es en sí bastante onomatopéyica, por lo que de *guacal* o *gualcada* se pasó a *guácala* como exclamación para expresar asco.